# Как правильно передать аргумент через указатель? C++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, недавно начал изучать C++, путаюсь с указателями. Допустим, есть такая функция.

```
void abcd(TCHAR *app){
    TCHAR tBufApp[256 + 1];
      wsprintf(tBufApp, _T("%s"), app); }
```

Вопрос 1) Нужно писать **&** перед **app** в ф-ии **wsprintf**? В каких случаях его вообще нужно писать (амперсанд)?

Вопрос 2) Правильно ли я вызываю функцию?

```
TCHAR app[256+1];
abcd(app);
```

Спасибо!

Comment: А по какой причине? Как это может повлиять?

Comment: Если кратко, то TCHAR это тип данных, который либо char либо wchar_t (в зависимости от настроек проекта) и его использование превращает портирование кода в адскую головную боль. подробнее про TCHAR тут: https://habrahabr.ru/post/164193/ .

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `&` -- получение адреса объекта, полученный адрес можно присвоить переменной-указателю:

```
int foo = 1;
int* ptr = &foo;
```

Оператор `*` -- разыменование указателя, т.е. получение значения переменной по адресу:

```
int bar = *ptr;
```

Кроме того, с++ позволяет неявное преобразование ссылки на массив в указатель на его первый элемент, т.е. данный код корректен:

```
int array[256];
int* p = array;
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Т.е, в моем случае все правильно? Или же при вызове нужно сделать как-то так abcd(&app); ?

Answer (score 2):

Кратко - 1) нет 2) да

`&` - это оператор получения адреса. `&app` - это адрес переданного в функцию аргумента, т.е. адрес ячейки памяти в стеке, куда он будет положен. Вам же в `sprintf` нужно передать адрес строки, из которой будет браться информация. Этот адрес содержится в самой переменной `app`, так что надо передать ее значение, а не ее адрес.

Глобально - когда нужно писать `&` - ответить однозначно и просто не получится, если не ограничиваться какими-то частностями. Упрощенно примерно так - надо просто понимать, что именно от вас ждут - какого-то значения, или указать, где это значение находится.

По второму вопросу - при передаче массива в функцию его имя заменяется адресом первого элемента, так что передаете вы все верно.